How do I fix neglected, leggy, woody lavender?
We have some neglected lavender in our back garden (Cheshire, UK). It gets partial sun and the soil is quite dense and rocky.
The lavender is very leggy and woody at the base. I feel like if I prune a third of the length it would still be limp and leggy.
In the first picture, you can just about see how it hangs over, not really able to support its own length.
What do I need to do it get it in better shape and keep it more aesthetically pleasing?
Thanks!



The problem is lack of sunlight - Lavender prefers full sun situations, so yours is groping forwards in an attempt to get more light. Lavender does not respond well to being cut back into old wood; the usual practice is to trim back about an inch to two inches all over twice a year, usually whilst removing spent flower heads. Even so, they still get leggy after a few years.
There's not much you can do with your Lavender, given the lack of light - if you have a full sun area, perhaps try planting a new one there instead.
